# Method in formatter.js isn't called

Tags: binding, path, sapui5, formatter

I wrote an SAPUI5 application in Eclipse with mockdata. When I call a specific method in formatter.js to fill an images source-property the method "formatMapUrl" isn't getting executed:

```
Object.view.xml:
   <Image src="{ parts: [ 'ToSupplier/Address/Street', 'ToSupplier/Address/PostalCode', 'ToSupplier/Address/City', 'ToSupplier/Address/Country' ], formatter: '.formatter.formatMapUrl' }"/>
```

Other methods of the file formatter.js are being called within the same file:

```
Object.view.xml:
<ObjectHeader id="objectHeader" title="{ProductID}" number="{ path: 'Price', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }"
                numberUnit="{CurrencyCode}" responsive="true">
```

This is the related method:

```
formatter.js:
    formatMapUrl : function (sStreet, sZIP, sCity, sCountry) {
        return "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=15&size=640x400&markers=" + jQuery.sap.encodeURL(sStreet + ", " + sZIP +  " " + sCity + ", " + sCountry);
    }
```

The method itself should be right too, cause I used it in other applications. The dynamic paths should be right (e.g. "ToSupplier/Address/Street"), cause I successfully used them in the same app and file like this:

```
Object.view.xml:
   <StandardListItem icon="sap-icon://map" title="{ToSupplier/Address/City}"/>
```

I tried to debug the app in the browser via the web console in firefox and found out that the method isn't getting executed.

In another application I created a model "Address.json" and successfully used it like this:

```
<Image src="{ parts: [ 'address>/Street', 'address>/ZIPCode', 'address>/City', 'address>/Country' ], formatter: '.formatter.formatMapUrl' }"/>
```

Comment: ~Have you set `data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"` in your bootstrap script? This requirement is often overlooked when using fomatters~ I now see other functions are being called so this is not the issue apparently

Comment: I tried - nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

The notation should be

```
<Image src="{
    parts: [
        { path: 'ToSupplier/Address/Street' }, 
        { path: 'ToSupplier/Address/PostalCode' }, 
        { path: 'ToSupplier/Address/City' }, 
        { path: 'ToSupplier/Address/Country' }
    ],
    formatter: '.formatter.formatMapUrl'
}" />
```

(Note each `path` property for the `parts` array)

Comment: Strange.... and if you narrow the function call down to just one parameter, i.e. `src="{ path: 'ToSupplier/Address/Street', formatter: '. formatter.formatMapUrl' }"` is the function then being called?

Comment: Ok all in all the line with "return" is being called 9 times.
1-5) None of the parameters are being filled.
6) Street ("Calvinstraße") 7) ZIP ("13467") 8) City ("Berlin") and 9) Country ("DE") is being filled. After the 9th execution every parameter is filled, but there's no picture of google maps: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=15&size=640x400&markers=Calvinstra%c3%9fe%2c%2013467%20Berlin%2c%20DE

Comment: I don't know what's going on but this is what I noticed through my debugging:
1) Now it is being executed only 4 times (Step 6-9). After this 4 steps the parameters are filled correctly.
2) The image is being build (!) but disappears very soon after.
3) With Opera and Chrome I figured out, that the image can't be displayed, the image address seems to be right (context menu > copy picture address). There's only a placeholder for the image.

Comment: Weird indeed... is there some DOM manipulation or view buildup which triggers a re-render and thus re-calling the formatter several times? Sorry I can't help you with this.... :(

Comment: As I'm informed - no... But how can I identify such code? "Sorry I can't help you with this.... :(" But you try - thanks for that! :)

Comment: Hard to be specific without seeing the full code, but you may try to set a breakpoint in the view controller onAfterRendering method and check the stack trace; also, look for multiple model load-and-control-rebinding, these may be indicators too

Answer (score 0):

Puh...that was very weird but I think I figured it out:
In my case images, presented by Google Maps, can't be shown in Firefox or Opera. It only worked with Google Chrome. I created some applications in SAPUI5 with data within models and there the maps are being shown in every browser but in apps with mockdata it seems to be not possible. Maybe because of binding? Or related processes? I don't know. I hope I could help someone with this. Thanks to Qualiture for your help! :)

Edit (25.07.2016):
Some of the pictures aren't being shown in Chrome too due to some reasons. First I thought that would be because of wrong addresses and I entered real addresses I know into the mockdata file. But nothing changed. Maybe it's a limitation of Google itself?

Edit (26.07.2016):
I debugged the application again. This time with Google Chrome Developer Tools. And there was some interesting error shown in the console: staticmap:1 GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=15&size=640x400&markers=Morning%20Drive%2c%2091602%20Hollywood%2c%20California%2c%20US 403 ()

So indeed, there are limitations by Google - depending on how many "gets" the user send to the api. Here is the link to the thread on SCN: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3936298